# How to create a table format of 81 columns which can fit into one page?

Tags: tables, formatting

I want to create a table of 81 columns in landscaped mode, tiny font is ok. I changed the `\documentclass` to landscape, however the font was still too big to fit in. Any suggestion or idea would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[landscape,6pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polynomial}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 8
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The *first* step should be to use a format like `|*{81}{c|}` for your column specification, rather than the hoards of `c|`'s.

Comment: would `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package be useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
Some text

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
{\scriptsize            %% or tiny
    \begin{tabular}{|*{81}{@{\,}c@{\,}|}}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 8
    \end{tabular}
}

Some text again
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options may include using `resizebox` or `scalebox` from `graphicx` package.